# Python call class syntax error

Tags: python, class, syntax-error

Why does this code have a syntax error and not run?

```
class AboutMe :
    def __init__(self, myname, myschool, myage):
        self.name = myname
        self.school = myschool
        self.age = myage

    def myName(self):
        return self.name

    def mySchool(self):
        return self.school

    def myAge(self):
        return self.age

myname=input('Enter your name: ')
myschool=input('Enter your school: ')
myage=int(input('Enter your age: ')

a=AboutMe(myname,myschool,myage) #syntax error in this line

print('\nHello!')
print('My name is %s, and I attend %s. I am %d years old.'
      %(a.myName(),a.mySchool(),a.myAge()))
```

Comment: There are closing parentheses missing on the line above it (`myage=int(...`)

Comment: myage=int(input('Enter your age: ')) missing `)`

Comment: Syntax error may occur in the previous line also :-)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I feel stupid^^''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myage=int(input('Enter your age: ')` is missing one more `)` at the end, so the next line causes error.

Comment: Oh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.... It's just that easy to fix. Thank you for your help. I may need some rest ^^"